# Issue with Static HTML Export in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new in nextJS and trying to deploy project in html.

```
Develop your app as you normally do with Next.js. Then run:

next build && next export
For that you may want to update the scripts in your package.json like this:

"scripts": {
  "build": "next build && next export"
}
And run it with:

npm run build
Then you'll have a static version of your app in the out directory.
```

above is from https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#how-to-use-it

On `npm run build` its creating out folder but it have only js files, index.html file is missing.

How to export nextJS project in html.

Thanks

**Update**

on export i am getting this error

```
Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
  Possible solutions:
    - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
    - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
    - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
    - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.
  Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api
```

Comment: Yes but nothing for index.html

Answer (score 6):

replacing `Image` with `img` and `npm run build`. Image optimization not supported `next export`

```
<img width={70} height={70} src="https://sun1.beTCOYGm.jpg" alt="мое фото" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `module.exports` in `next.config.js`:

```js
  experimental: {
    images: {
      unoptimized: true,
    },
  },
```

This turns off image optimization.

Read more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api

And here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized